# how to only show one set of data on a graph on vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to take data that is selected from a list box(files with the data) reading them out and then graphing them out. the issue is when I select the next item in the list box it keeps the graph from the previous file and plots the current file on top of it. I have set a integer N to define what files are needed to plot. I am using Chart.Titles.Clear() and Chart.series.Clear The title is not being added only the "series" do I have this in the right location or is there something I am missing?

```
Dim One01reader As IO.StreamReader
Dim One01One01_a_reader As IO.StreamReader
Dim MonitorIDTextFile As StreamWriter
Dim GrossGammaCountInCR1, MonitorRetrived, GrossGammaCountInCR2, GrossGammaCountInCR3, 
GrossGammaCountInCR4,
GrossGammaCountInCR5, GrossGammaCountInCR6, GrossGammaCountInCR7, GrossGammaCountInCR8, 
GrossGammaCountInS2N, GrossGammaCountInAverageFlow, GrossGammaCountInExpR,
GrossGammaCountInCR9, GrossGammaCountInCR10, GrossDateOfFile, GammaStatus, 
GammaApproveStatus, GammaApproveOrDisapproveStatus, MonitorID, ListboxSelection, S2N, 
ExposureRate, AverageFlowRate As String
Dim FileNameDateStringConversion As New List(Of DateTime)
Dim ExposureRateValues, S2NValues, ApproveStatusValues, AverageFlowRateValues, 
GammaCountsInCR1Values, GammaCountsInCR2Values, GammaCountsInCR3Values, 
GammaCountsInCR4Values, GammaCountsInCR5Values, GammaCountsInCR6Values, 
GammaCountsInCR7Values, GammaCountsInCR8Values, GammaCountsInCR9Values, 
GammaCountsInCR10Values As New List(Of Single)
Dim N, CountsofCR1Rows, CountsofCR2Rows, CountsofCR3Rows, CountsofCR4Rows, 
CountsofCR5Rows, CountsofCR6Rows, CountsofCR7Rows, CountsofCR8Rows, CountsofCR9Rows, 
CountsofCR10Rows, CountsOfApprovedStatus, CountsOfAverageFlowRateRows, 
CountsOfExposureRateRows, CountsOfS2NRows As Integer
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
MonitorLocationList.SelectedIndexChanged
    AcceptButton = NextBtn
    Dim FileNameRead As String
    Dim LinesForDateOfTheFile
    Dim LineCountForMonitor As Integer
    Try
        ListboxSelection = Me.MonitorLocationList.Text
        N = ListboxSelection.Substring(ListboxSelection.Length - 3)
        FileNameRead = "C:\R\storage\data\CRSWeeklyReview\MonitorTextFiles\" & N & 
".csv"
        'Try
        LineCountForMonitor = File.ReadAllLines(FileNameRead).Length - 2
    Catch
        MsgBox("No data is availble for " & ListboxSelection)
        If MonitorLocationList.SelectedIndex >= 0 AndAlso 
MonitorLocationList.SelectedIndex < MonitorLocationList.Items.Count - 1 Then
            MonitorLocationList.SelectedIndex += 1
        End If
    End Try
    ListboxSelection = Me.MonitorLocationList.Text
    N = ListboxSelection.Substring(ListboxSelection.Length - 3)
    ' Dim LinesForDateOfTheFile
    FileNameRead = "C:\R\storage\data\CRSWeeklyReview\MonitorTextFiles\" & N & ".csv"
    LineCountForMonitor = File.ReadAllLines(FileNameRead).Length - 2
    Dim TwoDArray(LineCountForMonitor, 62) As String
    LinesForDateOfTheFile = File.ReadAllLines(FileNameRead)
    For x_DOF = 1 To LineCountForMonitor
        Dim data = LinesForDateOfTheFile(x_DOF)
        Dim splits = data.Split(","c)
        For y_DOF = 0 To TwoDArray.GetUpperBound(1)
            TwoDArray(x_DOF, y_DOF) = splits(y_DOF)
            GrossDateOfFile = TwoDArray(x_DOF, 1)
        Next 'y_DOF
        FileNameDateStringConversion.Add(GrossDateOfFile)
    Next 'x_DOF
    MonitorID = TwoDArray(1, 0)
    CountsOfApprovedStatus = ApproveStatusValues.Count - 1

    '                                                 This defines the data if the 
approved box is checked
    If N = MonitorID Then
        If ChkBoxGammaApproved.Checked = True Then                '                                                                
 Defining CR1 (Approved)
            Dim linesForCR1 = 
File.ReadAllLines("C:\R\storage\data\CRSWeeklyReview\MonitorTextFiles\" & N & ".csv")
            For x_1 = 1 To LineCountForMonitor
                Dim data = linesForCR1(x_1)
                Dim splits = data.Split(","c)
                Dim StringConversion As Double
                For y_1 = 0 To TwoDArray.GetUpperBound(1)
                    TwoDArray(x_1, y_1) = splits(y_1)
                    GrossGammaCountInCR1 = TwoDArray(x_1, 44)
                    GammaStatus = TwoDArray(x_1, 61)
                    MonitorID = TwoDArray(x_1, 0)
                    If GammaStatus = "APPROVED" Then
                        GrossGammaCountInCR1 = TwoDArray(x_1, 44)
                    ElseIf GammaStatus = "DISAPPROVED" Then
                        GrossGammaCountInCR1 = 0
                    ElseIf GammaStatus = "WAIT" Then
                        GrossGammaCountInExpR = 0
                    ElseIf GammaStatus = "PRECHECK" Then
                        GrossGammaCountInExpR = 0
                    End If
                Next 'y_1
                StringConversion = CSng(GrossGammaCountInCR1)
                GammaCountsInCR1Values.Add(GrossGammaCountInCR1)
                CountsofCR1Rows = GammaCountsInCR1Values.Count - 1
            Next 'x_1
 Hourly_Chart.Series.Clear()
        Hourly_Chart.Titles.Clear()
        Hourly_Chart.Titles.Add(ListboxSelection) 'name of chart          
        Dim s = Hourly_Chart.Series.Add("X-Axis is the date range of selected files")
        With Hourly_Chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisX
            .Title = "Date"
            .IsLogarithmic = False
            s.XValueType = DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.DateTime
        End With
        With Hourly_Chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY
            .Title = "Counts or value"  'y title
            .IsLogarithmic = True
        End With
        '                          ****This starts to plot CR1 With approved *****     
        If ChkBoxCR1.Checked = True AndAlso ChkBoxGammaApproved.Checked = True Then
            Hourly_Chart.Series.Add("Channel Range 1")
            Hourly_Chart.Series("Channel Range 1").Color = Color.Yellow
            Hourly_Chart.Series("Channel Range 1").BorderWidth = 4
            Hourly_Chart.Series("Channel Range 1").ChartType = 
DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.FastPoint
            For i As Integer = 1 To CountsofCR1Rows
                Dim y1 As Single
                Dim x1 As Date
                x1 = FileNameDateStringConversion(i)
                y1 = GammaCountsInCR1Values(i)
                If y1 = 0 Then y1 = 1
                Hourly_Chart.Series("Channel Range 1").Points.AddXY(x1, y1)
            Next 'i
        End If ' CR1 Approved ends here
```